# Handle POST Requests through Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, http-post

I am trying to integrate TrialPay with Wordpress. TrialPay can send me either a POST or GET Request, and I have to receive it. When I send the response, there can be no HTML, only a "1" in the response.

I have tried a rewrite endpoint from some code someone gave me, but in the response the whole home page HTML is included.

```
  function wpd_trialpay_endpoint(){
        add_rewrite_endpoint( 'trialpay', EP_PAGES );
   }
  add_action( 'init', 'wpd_trialpay_endpoint' );

   function wpd_trialpay_parse( $request ){
if( array_key_exists( 'trialpay', $request->query_vars ) ){
    $toaward = $_GET['reward_amount'];
    $user = $_GET['sid'];

    if (mycred_add('Points_for_TrialPay_Offer', 1, 1, '%plural% for TrialPay offer completion', $_POST['oid'] )) {
        echo "1";
        //header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
 } else {
        echo "Fail!";
        //header("HTTP/1.1 412 Precondition Failed");
    }
    die;
  }
}
 add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpd_trialpay_parse' );
```

Is this the right way to do this? When I navigate to mysite.com/offer/trialpay (/offer is a blank page), the page outputs a "1" like intended. When I test the page with a POST request, it returns the whole front page HTML. What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried using `Exit` yet?

Comment: `Exit`? What are you referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a init action hook and manage all the post and get parameters in the callback function. here's an example:

```
Add_action('init','callback_function');
Function callback_function(){
// manage get and post variables here
}
```

this code is supposed to go in your plugin or inside functions.php if you're working with a theme

Comment: Thanks. A lot simpler than I thought.